# Resolve region manager in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, specflow

I am trying to do this in a specflow step definition file, so that I can create an object of view model and make method calls to it.

But I get an error saying "Interface cannot be resolved: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Regions.IRegionManager (resolution path: TestClass)". What is that I am doing wrong?

```
public class TestClass
{
    private IRegionManager _RegionManager;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public TestClass(IRegionManger regionManager)
    {
        this._RegionManager = regionManager;
        // stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you expecting your test class to be instantiated by SpecFlow or via Prism? As both have dependency injection functionality.

So I wouldn't expect your test definition file to have any importing constructors or similar MEF attributes. Instead I would expect your test class to written more like

```
[Binding]
public class TestClass
{
  [Given("I setup Prism")]
  public void GivenISetupPrism()
  {
    // Call into prism
  }
}
```

See the documentation on http://specflow.org for more details.

Comment: how do I make a call to prism in GivenISetupPrism() ? I am new to this.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any experience with prism, but since you are using specflow to run your tests it needs to wrap the prism instantiation in order to call into prism. If you have it the other way round the best you can hope for is a new GUI test runner. :-)